# getting 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr even when pos is less than length of string

Tags: substr, stdstring, outofrangeexception

I am running this code:

*

```
ifstream trace_file;
trace_file.open (argv[7]);
while (!trace_file.eof())
    {

        string line;
        getline (trace_file,line);
        string read_write = line.substr(0,1);

        string address = line.substr(2);

       cout << line << '\t' << read_write <<  "-->" << address<< "-->" << line.size() << '\n';

    }
```

*

The file that I am reading through ifstream, has this content:

```
r 4fd

w f47

r 8d2

w f05
```

I get this output:

```
r 4fd   r-->4fd-->5

w f47   w-->f47-->5

r 8d2   r-->8d2-->5

w f05   w-->f05-->5

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

  what():  basic_string::substr

Abort (core dumped)
```

It runs fine if I remove this line:

```
 string address = line.substr(2);
```

Length of each string is 5, so this should not throw this exception.

It runs fine if I keep pos=0

for pos = 1 or 2 or 3, I get this exception.

I do not understand what is wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.